# IBM DB2: Order by day

Tags: sql, db2

I have a column in my database that lists the days in the format "Monday", "Tuesday", etc:

Is there a way to order my result queries so that I get the result with Monday first, then Tuesday, then Wednesday, then Thursday and so on?

I checked a couple of answers but using case in order by doesn't seem to work.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I'm using this in a cursor in C

Comment: It would be good, if you provided your failed statement text along with error code and message you get instead of just "doesn't seem to work" statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the simplest method is a `case` expression:

```
order by (case dow
            when 'Monday' then 1
            when 'Tuesday' then 2
            when 'Wednesday' then 3
            when 'Thursday' then 4
            when 'Friday' then 5
            when 'Saturday' then 6
            when 'Sunday' then 7
          end)
```

You can shorted this using `locate()`, if you like:

```
order by locate(dow, 'Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday')
```

Comment: I had mentioned in my question that using case somehow doesn't work. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: What does "doesn't seem to work" and "somehow doesn't work" mean? Do You get an error?

Comment: @user7999116 . . . You should explain what the issue is.  These are syntactically correct `order by` clauses that do what your question asks.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but "somehow doesn't work" meant that it wouldn't display it ordered. I rewrote the code and used what I marked as an answer and then it did work.

Answer (score 0):

As you might already know, there is no SQL for your requirement.  But here would be a dirty workaround.

```
#!/bin/sh

# create objects
echo "aaa,Monday" > dat.csv
echo "xxx,Thursday" >> dat.csv
echo "ooo,Friday" >> dat.csv
echo "jjj,Saturday" >> dat.csv
echo "bbb,Tuesday" >> dat.csv
echo "ccc,Wednesday" >> dat.csv
echo "yyy,Sunday" >> dat.csv

db2 drop db db1
db2 create db db1
db2 connect to db1
db2 "create table t1 (c1 char(10), c2 char(10))"
db2 "load from dat.csv of del insert into t1"
db2 "select c1, c2 from t1"

# add c3 column and set day of week number there
db2 alter table t1 add column c3 int
db2 "update t1 set c3 = 1 where c2 = 'Monday'" 
db2 "update t1 set c3 = 2 where c2 = 'Tuesday'" 
db2 "update t1 set c3 = 3 where c2 = 'Wednesday'" 
db2 "update t1 set c3 = 4 where c2 = 'Thursday'" 
db2 "update t1 set c3 = 5 where c2 = 'Friday'" 
db2 "update t1 set c3 = 6 where c2 = 'Saturday'" 
db2 "update t1 set c3 = 7 where c2 = 'Sunday'" 

# order by c3, day of week number
db2 "select c1, c2 from t1 order by c3"
```

The first "select c1, c2 from t1" returns:

```
C1         C2
---------- ----------
aaa        Monday
xxx        Thursday
ooo        Friday
jjj        Saturday
bbb        Tuesday
ccc        Wednesday
yyy        Sunday
```

And the "select c1, c2 from t1 order by c3" returns:

```
C1         C2
---------- ----------
aaa        Monday
bbb        Tuesday
ccc        Wednesday
xxx        Thursday
ooo        Friday
jjj        Saturday
yyy        Sunday
```

Hope this helps.